# Proving divergence of $a_{n} = \frac{n^3+2}{n^2+3}.$

Tags: calculus

So, I know that a sequence diverges if for all $M > 0$, there exists $N$ such that, for all $n$, $n \geq N$ implies that $a_{n} > M$. What I've done so far:
I consider the inequality $M < \frac{n^3+2}{n^2+3}.$ Then $\frac{n^3+2}{n^2+3} < \frac{n^3+\alpha}{n^2+3}$ for $\alpha > 2..$ But I'm not really sure how to move on. I feel like I'm overlooking something simple.

Comment: When the degree of the expression in the numerator is higher than that in the denominator you can always use polynomial division. Also you could divide numerator and denominator by $n^2$ and see if that would help.

Comment: $M<\frac{n^3+2}{n^2+3}$ is not the nicest inequality to work with. But maybe you can find a smaller but more simple expression than $\frac{n^3+2}{n^2+3}$ and check when the smaller expression is bigger than $M$. For example, we have $\frac{n^3+2}{n^2+3}>\frac{n^3}{n^2+3}$. This new expression is already easier to work with. Now try to simplify it even more, before you get an expression which you can easily check when is it bigger than $M$. (and if for large enought $n$ it is bigger than $M$, then $\frac{n^3+2}{n^2+3}$, which is even bigger, will surely be bigger than $M$ for large enough $n$)

Comment: Thank you both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $n\geq 1$,

$$\frac{n^3+2}{n^2+3} = \frac{n^3(1+\frac{2}{n^3})}{n^2(1+\frac{3}{n^2})}=n\Big(\frac{1+\frac{2}{n^3}}{1+\frac{3}{n^2}}\Big)\geq n\Big(\frac{1+0}{1+3}\Big)=\frac{n}{4}$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: But $\frac{n}{4}$ is greater than $\frac{n^3+2}{n^2+3}$ for some $n$, no?

Comment: I doubt... and if it is the case, my answer is wrong.

Comment: Apologies! I just noticed that you said for $n \geq 1.$ Sorry, sorry.

Comment: Also, thank you! I was able to proceed.